# Is there a way to synchronize ngx-chart line chart so that when hovering over one, it will hover over the other charts at the same x value?

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am trying to implement multiple line chart from ngx-charts within a container to present data of multiple different types with the same x and y axis and it'd be nice to hover over one and the others will be mouseover with the tooltip displaying the data of the other charts at the same x value.

Comment: any update on this?